Which Emojis are supported by the Zendesk API? (It looks like a SUBSET of the ones the web UI supports!)
I use Zendesk ("ZD") developer API to update tickets with comments. I frequently put markdown into ticket comments (using the "body" item and not the "html_body" item when I do that), and it seems that some emoji's are supported, e.g. :boom: and :x:. Others seem to be supported in ZD's web interface, but they don't render via the API, e.g. :up arrow: or :chains:. The former render as expected in the resulting comment, and the latter just render as text.
Does anyone know what explains this and what the comprehensive list of API-supported emojis might be (so I don't have to come up with it myself)?
I can use unicode characters like \u2191 and \u2193 to get what I want in some cases, but emojis are so much more fun!
Some things I tried in hopes of teasing out any idiosyncrasies:

adding spaces before / after, e.g. :x: :chains: :boom: instead of :x::chains::boom. (In both cases, only the :x: and :boom" emojis rendered as expected)
searching the web and ZD's documentation


The issue is likely due to the fact that not all emojis supported in Zendesk’s web interface are supported via the API This discrepancy can be attributed to differences in how the web interface and the API handle and render emojis
Zendesk’s API and web interface might use different libraries or methods to render emojis. The web interface often has more comprehensive support for emojis, while the API might be limited to a subset of these emojis
